Having trouble using unweighted_n in header with gtsummary (version 2.0.1)

How to change the weighted N count in the column header ("N = 6,194") of the table above to unweighted n count?
The table was created with a default dataset using the following code:
library(gtsummary)
library(survey)
data(api)

svydesign(id = ~dnum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus1, fpc = ~fpc) |>
tbl_svysummary(include = c(api00, stype), 
               statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})", 
                                all_categorical() ~ "{n_unweighted} ({p}%)")) 

Thank you for your help!

To get the header with unweighted statistics. You'll first need to install the development version of the package. I've included code below to install and build the table. Hope it helps!
pak::pak("ddsjoberg/gtsummary")
#> ℹ Loading metadata database
#> ✔ Loading metadata database ... done
#> 
#> 
#> ℹ No downloads are needed
#> ✔ 1 pkg + 62 deps: kept 63 [1m 5.3s]
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '2.0.1.9002'

library(gtsummary)
library(survey)
data(api)

svydesign(id = ~dnum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus1, fpc = ~fpc) |>
  tbl_svysummary(
    include = c(api00, stype), 
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})", 
                     all_categorical() ~ "{n_unweighted} ({p}%)")
  ) |> 
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**N = {n_unweighted}**") |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on stackoverflow




Characteristic
N = 183




api00
644 (106)


stype



E
144 (79%)


H
14 (7.7%)


M
25 (14%)



Created on 2024-08-25 with reprex v2.1.1
Note: In your example, for the stype variable  we're mixing unweighted counts (n_unweighted) and weighted proportions (p).

Thanks for the help! I installed the development version successfully. But when I tried to run the code above to create the table, the following error occurred: Error: 'ard_total_n' is not an exported object from 'namespace:cardx'.
This is the error picture.
https://i.sstatic.net/BOwVfcEz.png

Ahh, I forgot there was a change in the way {remotes} handles Suggested deps (like {cardx}) compared to {pak}. Run pak::pak("insightsengineering/cardx") to get the dev version of {cardx}, which is also needed.

Problem solved. Thanks a lot!
